# UIColor not working with RGBA values

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am trying to change the text colour in a UITextField using the following code (RGBA value) however it just appears white, or clear, I'm not too sure as the background is white itself.

```
passwordTextField.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(202.0), green: CGFloat(228.0), blue: CGFloat(230.0), alpha: CGFloat(100.0))

passwordTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
passwordTextField.placeholder = "Password"
passwordTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
passwordTextField.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 14)
passwordTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = true
```

Comment: `202.0/255.0`, `228.0/255.0`, `230.0/255.0`, ect... the values should be between `0.0` and `1.0`...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

RGB values for UIColor are between 0 and 1 (see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a) "specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0")

You need to divide your numbers by 255:

```
passwordTextField.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(202.0/255.0), green: CGFloat(228.0/255.0), blue: CGFloat(230.0/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
```

Another thing, you don't need to create CGFloats:

```
passwordTextField.textColor = UIColor(red:202.0/255.0, green:228.0/255.0, blue:230.0/255.0, alpha:1.0)
```

Comment: Two years later this is still the only way! Surprisingly rarely mentioned anywhere else!

Answer (score 11):

Using convenience init ( code like a pro )

## Step 1

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
//let color = UIColor(red: 202/255, green: 228/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1) ☠️
let color = UIColor(r: 202, g: 228, b: 230) //
```

Comment: Only 1 step? :P

Answer (score 3):

try this instead :

```
passwordTextField.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.792, green: 0.894, blue: 0.901, alpha: 1.0
```

Always put substituted values. 202/255 = 0.792

Answer (score 2):

red, green, blue and alpha are supposed to be between 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, `UIColor` components are normalized in the range 0.0 ~ 1.0 (I think wide color gamuts are the exception, but haven't researched that yet).

A conveninet **extension** to the `UIColor` class will let you use values in the 0~255 range (like those obtained from various inspectors and image editing tools):

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    convenience init(
        redByte   red:UInt8,
        greenByte green:UInt8,
        blueByte  blue:UInt8,
        alphaByte alpha:UInt8
        ) {
        self.init(
            red:   CGFloat(red  )/255.0,
            green: CGFloat(green)/255.0,
            blue:  CGFloat(blue )/255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha)/255.0
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIColor convenient methods, from Integers, or from Hex.

```
extension UIColor {


    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, alpha: CGFloat) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: alpha)
    }



    convenience init(rgb: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(
            red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
            green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
            blue: rgb & 0xFF,
            alpha: alpha
        )
    }
}
```