# swift 3 can not assign right color to label's background color

Tags: colors, swift3, background, set, label

I am trying to assign color to  label's background color.

I have tried both way

```
label1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 69, blue:0, alpha: 1).cgColor
```

and

```
label2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 69, blue:0, alpha: 1)
```

but after I run in simulator ,or device, above two label show wrong color, it show yellow color,there.

correct color is organge `red( 255,69,0)`

any idea what it is ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIColor not working with RGBA value, iOS 7 - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310696/uicolor-not-working-with-rgba-value-ios-7-swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
label.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 69/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to divide it from `255` then only you can get the `RGB` colour. do it like below

```
label.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 69/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1);
```