# UITableView cell background custom color

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, uicolor

I play with UITableView cell background color and it works if I do it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor? = UIColor.yellow
}
```

but it doesn't if I try custom color

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor? = UIColor(red: 255, green: 197, blue: 2, alpha: 1)
}
```

What I have to do to make custom RGB color possible?

Comment: Because you need to read carefully the doc. The values must be between 0 and 1. so `UIColor(red: 255/255., green: 197/255., blue: 2/255., alpha: 1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIColor not working with RGBA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310696/uicolor-not-working-with-rgba-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write :

```
UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 197/255, blue: 2/255, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using convenience init

## Step 1

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) {
        self.init(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
//let color = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 197/255, blue: 2/255, alpha: 1) ☠️
let color = UIColor(r: 255, g: 197, b: 2) //
```